# No git branching information in cmder

Tags: windows, command-line, git, cmder

[image]Recently set up Git for windows and Cmder on a fresh Win 10 install. All the other Unix and git bash commands all work fine. I just can't see what branch I'm on that normally displays after the path. Environmental variables are all default as per installs of the two aforementioned softwares.

I'm guessing I may have to tweak tasks commands in Cmder settings but not sure what to. Any suggestions?

Current system env paths related are:

`C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;`

`C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;`

`C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;`

`C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;`

`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;`

`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;`

Comment: I suggest you to post screenshot demonstrating the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to your cropped screenshot I think you are using ConEmu, but not a cmder. At least, you are using "native" ConEmu task! To enable git information there you have to add `/git` switch after `CmdInit.cmd` in task contents.

One may read more about [Tasks](https://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html) in documentation. That's what docs were written for.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. For further understanding of these tasks and how they are used/allocated in the session, do you have a link to explain this and the differences between ConEmu and cmder?

Comment: cmder is a **software bundle**. That's the difference.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Cheers.